# Running python script on Microsoft Azure

Tags: python, azure, cloud, bigdata, azure-virtual-machine

I'll have a linux machine with a virtual machine installed for Microsoft azure soon. I need to run some data mining/graph analysis algorithms on the azure because I work with big data. I don't want to use azure machine learning stuff. just want to run my own python code. What are the steps? If needed, hoe can I install python libraries on azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no additional steps to do in comparison to Your own. local server. Linux on Azure is a standard Linux machine. If You are looking for step-by-step hopw to on running Linux VM on Azure, just search on azure.com and You will find it. I think You will not have any problems even without documentation. Azure portal is very simple to use, also CLI tool for Linux, Mac and Windows. You just need to run Linux VM and SSH-in to it. Nothing more. If You need some help, just write here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have the system set up and just want to run my python codes on it to use computation power of cloud. So as you said it should be quiet straightforward yes?

Comment: Yes. Just deploy Your code like on any other Linux machine.